# EXC_BAD_ACCESS on 8 line spritekit code

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, exc-bad-access, autorelease

My incredibly short app code somehow generates an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error. I have reproduced the error on a completely fresh app. But I can not comprehend how this happens.

Here is the entire code for my app (aside from what xcode generates automatically for a spritekit game).

```
-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {
    SKNode* pFirst = [SKNode node];
    [self addChild:pFirst];
    //
    SKSpriteNode* pSprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"img61.png"];
    pSprite.centerRect = CGRectMake(0.4,0.4, 0.2, 0.2); // suspect 1
    pSprite.position = CGPointMake(0,0);
    pSprite.xScale = 2.0;
    pFirst.alpha = 0.0;             //  suspect 2
    //
    [pFirst addChild:pSprite];    
}
```

The debugger places the crash point here:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

How can I understand what is wrong here?

Of course, this problem originally comes from a much longer app that was crashing. This is what code I had left when I simplified it, but preserved the crash.

Two lines are marked as "suspects". Amazingly, the code runs fine if EITHER suspect1 or suspect2 are removed. I can not comprehend this at all.

Comment: Can you upload your test app somewhere?

Comment: Yes, I will try to do that. But the steps to make from scratch are rather short:

Comment: (1) File->new->project
(2) select IOS Application -> GAme
(3) Change Technology to "SpriteKit
(4) paste the code above into didMoveToView

Comment: This link to a zip file of my project:   https://www.dropbox.com/s/sa79u2k9qj1aruq/crashExample.zip?dl=0

Comment: (And thanks for your interest in helping)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may find some hint from the description of `centerRect`,

> A property that defines how the texture is applied to the sprite.

So if you set `centerRect` of a sprite along with setting its `alpha = 0.0`, the alpha blended into the framebuffer will be 0 (See [Creating a Textured Sprite](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Sprites/Sprites.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013043-CH9-SW35) for more information). From the current case we just tested, the zero-alpha sprite is treated as a null sprite. So adding a child node to the null sprite will cause crash.

To solve the problem, one method is to change `pFirst.alpha = 0.0;` to `pFirst.hidden = YES;`. An alternative is to set the alpha after a sprite rendered to the scene. In your **didMoveToView** method, assign an identifier for `pFirst`,

```
pFirst.name = @"firstNode"
```

Then, add the following method to set alpha to zero after physics simulations are performed,

```
- (void)didSimulatePhysics
{
    [self enumerateChildNodesWithName:@"firstNode" usingBlock:^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop) {
        if (node.alpha > 0.0) {
            node.alpha = 0.0;
        }
    }];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in helping.   And thanks for telling me what you noticed.   I am not sure I feel comfortable to solve the problem in this way. If I do not understand what is causing this problem, I am very nervous to make a mysterious fix like that.

Comment: @JohnDorsey Someone reported this bug: http://openradar.appspot.com/18478101. I will try to find more about it.

Comment: Wow. That does explain everything perfectly. I just never imagined that IOS could have such a hideous bug as this.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reference you provided.

Comment: Wow. What awesome detective work, and helpful explanations + suggestions. A thousand thanks.

Comment: @JohnDorsey Glad it helps!